# creating an SQL view and schema using given fields and allias

Tags: sql-server

[image]

hi guys please could yo help me with the above question, I don't understand how to tackle it. I am required to create a SQL view as well as a schema based on given information (in the above picture). The main difficulty is the filter which i have never done before.

Comment: step by step. First write a `SELECT` query to retrieve the required column name. then you add `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` query. That is the filtering that is required. Give it a try and show us your query

Comment: We need to see how to generate the view to answer your question.  The "filter" is probably just a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Wow, images of the homework page itself. I do hope you accept images of answers.